# Is there a way to filter out values in a pandas dataframe column that has the same format?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am a beginner in python and I am trying to find out if there is a method to find of if the values of a cell in a column of a pandas dataframe follows a certain format?

For example,

```
1234_ABC_12 passes
4567_ABC_12 passes
```

but,

```
123A_ABC_12 fails
```

I have tried something like this, but it does not work.

```
for item in df[col].item():
    if item !=  ('\d\d\d\d_ABD_\d\d')
        print('fail')
    else:
        print('success')
```

Please help and suggest a better way to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str.match`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html)

```py
df
             a
0  1234_ABC_12
1  4567_ABC_12
2  123A_ABC_12

df.a.str.match('\d\d\d\d_ABC_\d\d')
0     True
1     True
2    False
```